# How to export XML file in CLOB column using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, informatica

I have an XML file in a `CLOB` column, which is present in an Oracle table. I would like to export the XML file into LINUX landing directory which will be done through Informatica. Can you help me out in how to do this. Please share your thoughts.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Developer ( I used version 3.2.20.09 )

*http:/WWW.Oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html*

Select ***Export*** from the right hand context menu

[Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cDZl.png)

1. Select the ***Export Data*** checkbox
2. Select ***Loader*** from the Format dropdown
3. Select ***Separate*** Files from the Save as dropdown
4. Enter the name of a directory
5. Click ***Next***
6. Click ***Finish***

[Export Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Cib.png)

It exports the data to separate files but at least it's in clear text.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file stored in cleartext in one of the fiels i.e. not binary or something?

If so then pick the field up in your source qualifier and parse it to a flat file made up of one port e.g. file_in .

If not, could you elaborate the error you are receiving in your current job and describe how the job works?